# Pandas dataframe searching by 3 columns and criteria

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `dataframe` of census data from the united states.  Columns include `STNAME` (state name) `CTYNAME` (county name) and many columns of different pieces of data collected in census reports by year.

I am looking for the top 3 most populous states, only including the top 3 most populous counties per states.

here is my current code which straightens up the original dataframe a bit and only includes what is relevant to the problem:

```
def answer():
    census_df50 = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
    columns = ['STNAME', 'CTYNAME', 'CENSUS2010POP']
    c = census_df50[columns]
    return c
print(answer())
```

and here is an example of the dataframe printed in the terminal:

```
     STNAME             CTYNAME  CENSUS2010POP
1       Alabama      Autauga County          54571
2       Alabama      Baldwin County         182265
3       Alabama      Barbour County          27457
4       Alabama         Bibb County          22915
5       Alabama       Blount County          57322
6       Alabama      Bullock County          10914
7       Alabama       Butler County          20947
8       Alabama      Calhoun County         118572
```

it is listed alphabetically by state then county, so this only shows the census data for alabama by county name, but there are over 3000 lines in the dataframe (one for each county, states have multiple entries)

My approach would be to write a function find the top 3 counties in `CTYNAME`, based on their `CENSUS2016POP` value (an integer representing population in 2010), for each state in column `STNAME`.  Then have the function return the names as strings of the top 3 states by this criteria. Pretty lost on how to accomplish this, however.

i am pretty sure i should be trying to use a combination of these functions `.groupby()`,  `.set_index()` and  `.nlargest()`.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It'd be great if you could post a sample of your data in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any sample data, here's some:

```
STNAME,CTYNAME,POPULATION
A,A1,100
A,A2,20
A,A3,30
A,A4,40
B,B1,10
B,B2,2
B,B3,30
B,B4,40
C,C1,100
C,C2,20
C,C3,300
C,C4,40
D,D1,10
D,D2,20
D,D3,30
D,D4,40

In [1]: df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

Here's a way to achieve the desired result, maybe there's simpler but I couldn't reduce it further:

```
In [2]: df.ix[df['STNAME'].isin(df.groupby('STNAME')['POPULATION'].sum().nlargest(3).index)].groupby(['STNAME','CTYNAME']).sum()['POPULATION'].groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(3)
```

---

To decompose:

```
# Find the first STNAME Groups
In [3]: largest_states = df.groupby('STNAME')['POPULATION'].sum().nlargest(3).index
        largest_states

Out[3]: Index(['C', 'A', 'D'], dtype='object', name='STNAME')
```

Filter the df on these:

```
In [4]: df2 = df.ix[df['STNAME'].isin(df.groupby('STNAME')['POPULATION'].sum().nlargest(3).index)]
```

Then find the first three within:

```
In [5]: df2.groupby(['STNAME','CTYNAME']).sum()['POPULATION'].groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(3)

Out[5]:
STNAME  CTYNAME
A       A1         100
        A4          40
        A3          30
C       C3         300
        C1         100
        C4          40
D       D4          40
        D3          30
        D2          20
Name: POPULATION, dtype: int64
```

---

**Update:**

If you want it to be sorted by state population, do it in this order:

```
In[6]: df2 = df.groupby(['STNAME','CTYNAME']).sum()['POPULATION'].groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(3)

       df2.ix[df.groupby('STNAME')['POPULATION'].sum().nlargest(3).index]

Out[6]:
STNAME  CTYNAME
C       C3         300
        C1         100
        C4          40
A       A1         100
        A4          40
        A3          30
D       D4          40
        D3          30
        D2          20
Name: POPULATION, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! looking through it now. thanks for the advice as well. I just edited my question to add some of my original code and a sample of there output of the dataframe.